# Split Test Script Errors, Wordpress vs. Not-Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to split test a mobile landing page using a simple script, and am getting some errors I don't understand that may have to do with the difference between Wordpress pages and static html pages on the same server.

The script worked as intended when I set it up for basic testing, accessing the initial URL via a desktop browser; it served up first one Wordpress landing page and then the alternate version. Here's the script:

```
    <?php

$file = fopen("redirect-count.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
$number = fgets($file);
fclose($file);

/* IMPORTANT: don't remove Location text in front of link, just change link to what you want */

if($number % 2 == 0){
    increase_number($number);
    header("Location: http://www.radionowheremusic.com/mobile.html/");  //<---------------------- URL 1
}
else{
    increase_number($number);
    header("Location: http://www.radionowheremusic.com/mobile2.html/");  //<---------------------- URL 2
} 

function increase_number($num){
    $file = fopen("redirect-count.txt","w") or exit("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($file, $num + 1);
    fclose($file);
}
?>`
```

However, what I want it to use it for is split testing two versions of a mobile landing page, both of which are static pages outside the WP loop.

When I replaced the two (initially WP) URLs in the script with the static URLs I actually want (the ones that are in there now, visible above), I got a 404 page from Hostgator when I tried to access the folder containing the script:

http://www.radionowheremusic.com/split

I don't have a sufficient rep to post images yet, but let me know if seeing an image of the 404 page would help (it appears to be Hostgator's standard).

I'm getting pretty confused here - any ideas as to what might be wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the last slash in both links:

```
header("Location: http://www.radionowheremusic.com/mobile.html"); //Removed trailing slash.
```

You have some issues in your code, it seems too fragile, but the problem you mentioned may be solved by this modification.